# Is this a type of jelly bean plant or something else?

Tags: identification, succulents, sedum

The difference between this and the well known "jelly bean plant" ([Sedum rubrotinctum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum_rubrotinctum)) is that this is edgy/pointy. I was searching for it everywhere on Google, but no trace found. Can someone tell me this plant's name?

[image: the_plant]

Comment: Did you find this plant in wild (where?) or it is cultivated?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it is cultivated. It was in a bowl in front of a store.

Comment: Perhaps Sedum morganianum. There is a variety that has the longer, pointier leaves. http://www.hmaplants.com/varieties/sedum-morganianum-pointed-leaf/

Comment: Try looking through [here](http://www.sedumphotos.net/main.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in a botanical garden and it is [Sedum rupestre/Sedum reflexum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum_reflexum). There are two varieties of this species and you can tell them apart when they bloom. One has upright flower stems, the other one has somewhat curved flower stems.

[image]